# Update linked excel path in PowerPoint via Python

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to automate creating of a powerpoint ppt via linking template charts to some Excel files. Updating the excel file values changes the powerpoint slides automatically. I have created my powerpoint template and linked charts to sample excel files data.

I want to send the folder with the powerpoint and excel files to someone else. But this will break the link to excel files due to change in the path. (As path is not relative). I can edit the paths manually by going under the "edit links to files" option under File Menu but this is tedious as charts are numerous with multiple files.

I want to update the same via Python code using the Python-Pptx package.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

There's no API support for this in the current version of `python-pptx`.

You would need to modify the underlying XML directly, perhaps using `python-pptx` internals as a starting point and using `lxml` calls on the appropriate element objects. If you search on "python-pptx workaround function" you will find some examples.

Another thing to consider is modifying the XML by cruder but still possibly effective means by accessing the XML files in the .pptx package directly (the .pptx file is a Zip archive of largely XML files) and using regular expressions or perhaps a command line tool like `sed` or `awk` to do simple text substitution.

Either way you're going to need to want it pretty badly, depending on your Python skill level. You'll also of course need to discover just which strings in which parts of the XML are the ones that need changing. `opc-diag` can be helpful for that, but it's a bit of detective work even with the best tools.